# How to model a joint distribution that does not have a pf/pdf?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Imagine $X$ and $Y$ are the times at which two components in a system fail. There's some probability $p$ that they fail at the same time and $1-p$ that they fail at different times. If they fail simultaneously with pdf $f(x)$ and fail at different times with pdf $g(x,y)$, then from what I understand, the joint distribution does not have a pf/pdf.

Question: how do we typically model such joint distributions?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to model: if you need both to fail for the system to fail, you will be able to find a distribution for system failure; if either failing causes system failure then again you will be able to find a distribution for system failure.  You can also find a distribution for component A to fail, and similarly a distribution for component B to fail.  So the only issue is the density of the joint distribution, and even there you can find a joint cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Yes the joint distribution has no density, but you already modelled it. So the question is, what do you want to do with this model, not how to model the situation... For example, you might use the fact that for every measurable bounded $u$, $$E(u(X,Y))=p\int u(x,x)f(x)\mathrm dx+(1-p)\iint u(x,y)g(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: @Dmitri Nesteruk something wrong with the answer, buddy?

Comment: @Karl no, nothing, I upvoted

Comment: @Dmitri Nesteruk, if you have asked a question, then you as OP can accept an answer, this gives a green tick left to the answer. Since you didn't do it, I thought something is not ok with it for you ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Setting $F_1(x)$ the cdf for the pdf $f(x)$ and $G(x,y)$ the joint cdf of $g(x,y)$, then for $F(x,y)=P(X<x, Y<y)$:

$ F(x,y)= 
P(\mbox{both fail at the same time z})P(z<x, z<y\ |\ \mbox{ both fail a.t.s.t.})
+P(\mbox{both fail at different times})P(X<x,Y<y\ |\  \mbox{both fail a.d.t.})
\\= p F_1(\min(x,y))+(1-p) G(x,y)$